# Documentation for the webkit developer tools' `window.console._commandLineAPI`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I discovered that if I step out of a function invoked in the chrome dev console, I end up in this source code:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
myFunction()
}
```

There are a few questions related to this describing some strange quirks in the console, but they're not relevant here.

If I type `window.console._commandLineAPI` into the console, I get a whole bunch of member names, some of which are more helpful than others:

```
$$: function () { [native code] }
$_: undefined
$x: function () { [native code] }
clear: function () { [native code] }
copy: function () { [native code] }
dir: function () { [native code] }
dirxml: function () { [native code] }
get $0: function () { [native code] }
get $1: function () { [native code] }
get $2: function () { [native code] }
get $3: function () { [native code] }
get $4: function () { [native code] }
getEventListeners: function () { [native code] }
inspect: function () { [native code] }
keys: function () { [native code] }
monitorEvents: function () { [native code] }
profile: function () { [native code] }
profileEnd: function () { [native code] }
set $0: undefined
set $1: undefined
set $2: undefined
set $3: undefined
set $4: undefined
unmonitorEvents: function () { [native code] }
values: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: CommandLineAPI
```

Is there any documentation anywhere on what these functions do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the FireBug [command line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API).